# cannot read lifecycle mapping metadata for artifact org.apache.maven.plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I have the links of people who have the same error but it seems they are trying to import a project. I deleted and reinstalled the spring plug in via the Eclipse Marketplace as recommended but that does't work.

I create a maven project then click finish and none of the src files populate. Right away the pom.xml file shows the dreadful red X. Once I click it to see what is going on "cannot read lifecycle mapping metadata for artifact org.apache.maven.plugins" is displayed.

I am using Apache 8, Java SDK 8 and here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.learnprograming</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-helloworld</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

I have done this same process on my other computer and I was able to create a spring program. I get on my macbook and I get nothing but issues!

Comment: m2e plugin installed in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes. I just reinstalled it just in case that was a corruption I was looking for. I then decided to deleted the program and try again and got the same error.

Comment: I also tried to delete my ~/.m2/repository and that did not work either. I seen that was a suggestion on a spring forum.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the nexus. I have experienced this problem because Set this attribute in settings.xml. Removing it will resolve this problem. I hope it will help you!

```
<mirrors>    
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```